# Opencv in python gives me a AttributeError

Tags: python-3.x, opencv, imshow

Im trying to get opencv working for a face recognition program. My webcam is working since I tested it using cv2.VideoCapture and the window popped up, then when i added the next step which is turning the image gray using cv2.cvtcolor(frame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY) I got the error message saying AttributeError: module 'cv2.cv2' has no attribute 'cvtcolor. I tried uninstalling and reinstalling opencv using pip3 install opencv-contrib-python. Im not sure what im doing wrong here, my guess is maybe my files arnt in the write place but im not sure where they would need to be

When I use this code my window of my webcam pops up and works fine.
[Working code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0ZYup.png)

```
import os 
import PIL
import cv2
import numpy


face_cascade = cv2.CascadeClassifier(cv2.data.haarcascades + 
"haarcascade_frontalface_alt2.xml")

cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)

while(True):
    #frame by frame
    ret, frame = cap.read()
    gray = cv2.cvtcolor(frame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
   faces = face_cascade.detectMultiscale(gray, scaleFactor=1.5, 
minNeighbors=5)

    #display frame
    cv2.imshow('frame',frame)
    if cv2.waitKey(20) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
        break


        #when done relase cap


cap.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:/Users/Nick Miller/all_for_vs/Code/facerecg.py", line 14, in 
    gray = cv2.cvtcolor(frame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
AttributeError: module 'cv2.cv2' has no attribute 'cvtcolor'
[ WARN:0] terminating async callback

Comment: cvtcolor is a typo

Answer (score 0):

Change 
`cv2.cvtcolor(frame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)` to `cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)`.

Also, change `faces = face_cascade.detectMultiscale(gray,scaleFactor=1.5,minNeighbors=5)` to `faces = face_cascade.detectMultiScale(gray,scaleFactor=1.5,minNeighbors=5)`

Comment: Yes I changed that but now I have an error on the detectMultiscale

Comment: check updated answer. It will be `face_cascade.detectMultiScale`